# strophe connect openfire error

Tags: openfire, strophe

I input a jid and pwd on a html form, and use Strophe to connect to openfire, but when I press the login button, the xmpp server response is error 302.
I enabled the option on openfire, and restarted it.

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://ip:7070/http-bind';
    $('#btn-login').click(function() {
    if(!connected) {
        connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
        connection.connect($("#input-jid").val(), $("#input-pwd").val(), onConnect);
        jid = $("#input-jid").val();
    }
});
```

It seems a little harder than to use smack in java because of the network problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the uri specified in `BOSH_SERVICE`.

Correct uri is:

> `http://ip:7070/http-bind/`

Pay attention to the **/** at the bottom of the string.

Comment: thank you for sharing your experience. Could you help me check the code below this quesion? my connect is still failed. Even there is no http request ,when I open the developer tools to monitor the http activity

Comment: please post a complete sample of code, so we can help you. did you edit the url?